# Ruby on Rails warning при запуске RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warning

Доброго времени суток!

При запуске RSpec постоянно вылазит warning, на работоспособность он не влияет, но хотелось бы все таки устранить его.

```
niks@Nikita-PC:~/RoR/sample_app$ bundle exec rspec spec/
/home/niks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/niks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/home/niks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/niks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin in PATH, mode 040777
```

Гуглил, читал, пишут, что проблема в том, что не хватает прав. Пробовал выдавать права 777 рекурсивно на /home/niks/, но к сожалению это ничего не дало.

Решение проблемы:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user_name/.rvm/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас папка /home/niks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin почему-то имеет права доступа 0777, которые система считает излишне широкими с точки зрения безопасности. Измените её на 0755

```
sudo chmod 0755 /home/niks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
```

Comment: Сделал, не помогло, обновил сообщение.

Comment: Вы ставите права 777, а надо меньше. Insecure в сообщении сигнализирует, что у вас не безопасные права доступа. 777 - это доступно всем, поставьте хотя бы 775, а еще лучше 755.

Comment: Обновил для Вас первое сообщение.

Comment: ага, спасибо, а в ошибке права остались 0777 или выводит 0755, какие-то изменения имеются?

Comment: Сделал sudo chmod -R 755 .rvm/ и ошибка полностью ушла, спасибо!